# Binomial Probabilities of Dogs Performing Tricks

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Marcus is attempting to take some photographs of the four show dogs he is training. For simplicity let's call the four dogs $A, B, C$ and $D$. The probability that each dog will perform a trick when Marcus tells them to so he can take a photograph is $0.05, 0.07, 0.15$ and $0.2$ respectively, independently of each other, and independently between photos.

---

My solution so far,

***Events:***

$\hspace{2cm}$  $A$ : "dog $A$ performs a trick" $\hspace{2cm}$         $B$ : "dog $B$ performs a trick"

$\hspace{2cm}$  $C$ : "dog $C$ performs a trick"   $\hspace{2cm}$    $D$ : "dog $D$ performs a trick"

***Probabilities:***

$\hspace{4cm}$  $Pr(A) = 0.05$ $\hspace{3cm}$     $Pr(B) = 0.07$

$\hspace{4cm}$  $Pr(C) = 0.15$ $\hspace{3cm}$     $Pr(D) = 0.20$

**(a)**  If Marcus attempts $20$ group photographs, what is probability that at least half of them have all four dogs not doing a trick?

Firstly we require the probability that none of the dogs do a trick in a single photo,

$\begin{align}Pr(A'B'C'D') &= Pr(A')Pr(B')Pr(C')Pr(D') \\&= 0.95\times0.93\times0.85\times0.20 \\&= 0.60\end{align}$

Let $X$ denote "the number of photos in 20 without all four dogs doing a trick". Now, using the binomial theorem,

$\begin{align} Pr(10 \leq X \leq 20) &= 20C10(0.60)^{10}(0.40)^{10} + 20C11(0.60)^{11}(0.40)^{9}...20C20(0.60)^{20}(0.40)^{0} \\&= 0.117 + 0.160 + ... + 0\\& = 0.872\end{align}$

**(b)** If Marcus takes $10$ individual photographs of $A$, what is the probability that he will have performed a trick in fewer than $2$ of them?

Let $A$ now denote "the number of photos in $10$ where $A$ does a trick",

$\begin{align} Pr( 0\leq A \leq 1) &= Pr(A=0) + Pr(A=1)\\&= 10C0(0.05)^0(0.95)^10 + 10C1(0.05)^1(0.95)^9\\&= 0.60 + 0.32\\&= 0.92  \end{align}$

**(c)** What is the probability that Marcus will need to take at least $3$ individual photographs of dog $C$ until he has one where $C$ has performed a trick?

**(d)** Marcus wants $5$ good group photos of his dogs, how much can he expect to pay if each photo he attempts costs $\$1.25$ to develop?

---

I've included my attempts at (a) and (b) to make sure I'm on the right track. However, I'n not sure how to approach the last two?

Any answers or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (c) What is the probability that Marcus will need to take at least $3$ individual photographs of dog $C$ until he has one where $C$ has performed a trick?

Marcus will need to take at least $3$ individual photographs of dog $C$ if this dog will not performs a trick in the first two trials. The probability of this event is $(1-0.15)^2$.

> (d) Marcus wants $5$ good group photos of his dogs, how much can he expect to pay if each photo he attempts costs $\$1.25$ to develop?

If "good group photo" describes the situation when all four dogs perform a trick, then you find in (a) the probability $0.6$ of single photo to be good. The number of photos $N$ that needed to get one good photo is geometrically distributed:
$$
P(N=k)=0.6(1-0.6)^{k-1},\, k=1,2,3,\ldots
$$ 
The expected value of $N$ is $$EN=\frac{1}{0.6}=\frac53$$ 
The same expected number of photos is required to get second good photo after the first is obtained, then to get third and so on.

So you can get the expected number of photos required to get $5$ good photos. And the expected number of money to paid.

Comment: With c), is it possible to use the negative binomial formula?

Comment: No. No need in this formula and no place for it to appear. The probability that two fails occured in two trials is calculated by product of probabilities of fails is each trial.

Comment: Okay, no worries -  I think I was just over thinking it. Thanks NCh!